# Youtube data api key not working all time

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data API to list all youtube videos. After one day, my videos are not retrieving. If I change youtube data API key then I can able to retrieve youtube videos my site [HDBUDDY](http://hdbuddy.com/)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using OAuth or do you have to use an API key?

Comment: no i dint tried

Comment: i have tio use api key

Comment: please any help??

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).